# Making the definition of dual root unambiguous

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, algebraic-groups, reductive-groups

In 5.4 of his book *Lectures on Invariant Theory*, [Igor Dolgachev introduces the **dual** of a root](http://books.google.de/books?id=B9S_0iPvfrUC&lpg=PP1&dq=lectures%20on%20invariant%20theory&hl=de&pg=PA76#v=snippet&q=%22Let%20us%20now%20describe%20dominant%20weights%22&f=false) by requiring that

1. $\check\alpha(t) f_\alpha(x) \check\alpha^{-1}(t)= f_\alpha(x)$
2. $(\alpha\circ\check\alpha)(t)=t^2$, i.e. $\langle\alpha,\check\alpha\rangle=2$.

He earlier defined a **root** to be a multiplicative character $\alpha:T\to\mathbb{G}_{\mathrm{m}}$ of the torus such that there exists an additive one-parameter subgroup $f_\alpha:\mathbb{G}_{\mathrm{a}}\to G$ with 
$$ \forall t\in T: \forall x\in\Bbbk: t\cdot f_\alpha(x)\cdot t^{-1} = f_\alpha(\alpha(t)x).$$
Now by the above and (2), we have to have 
$$\check\alpha(t) f_\alpha(x) \check\alpha^{-1}(t)= f_\alpha((\alpha\circ\check\alpha)(t) x)
 = f_\alpha(t^2 x).$$
which is a contradiction to (1), at least in general. Now, I am worried that he means something else by (1) because $\check\alpha$ is not uniquely defined when requiring only (2). In fact, in the example given, one could define either
\begin{align*}
\check\alpha(t) &:= I_r + (t-1)E_{ii} + (t^{-1}-1)E_{ii} & \text{or}\\
\check\alpha(t) &:= I_r + (t^2-1)E_{ii} - E_{ii}
\end{align*}
and both would satisfy (2).

The question is, which additional condition is needed to make this definition of a dual root unambiguous?

**Edit** Maybe I should have said this right away: I would expect that the additional condition should be that $\beta-\langle\check\alpha,\beta\rangle\alpha$ is a root for all roots $\beta$. This would be coherent with the corresponding definition of abstract root systems. However, I am not sure if I am missing something.

Comment: I find the notation a bit confusing since $t$ is used to represent both elements from $T$ and from $\mathbb{G}_m$.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: It's the notation from Dolgachev's book, I would personally use different notation as well.

Comment: I will need to think about this some more I think. I am only used to the definition of coroots like done in for example Jantzen, where one uses the homomorphism from $SL_2$ to the group for each root in order to define the coroot.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: See my edit.